# How to make widgets of QStackedWidget in QScrollArea resize automatically?

Tags: qt, qt5

I've been trying to resize pages (widgets) of a QStackedWidget residing in a QScrollArea. Unfortunately, I didn't make it. Before searching for some particular persons, the page 1 widget (`full_list_frame`)  resized automatically. But after the searching, the size of the page 2 widget (`search_list_frame`) remained the same as that of the page 1 widget. What I expected is that each page of the stacked widget can resize automatically based on how many widgets/items their layout has, which means the page cannot be scrolled if the size is not large enough to be scrolled.

Or maybe this problem was caused by the QScrollArea or something else? When I hard-coded to change the size of the page 2 widget (`search_list_frame`) and printed that out. The output showed the changed size, but it still didn't change anything shown on screen.

**xxx.cpp**

```
void XXX::initComponents()
{
    list_scroll_area = new QScrollArea(this);
    //list_scroll_area->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
    list_scroll_area->setWidgetResizable(true);
    list_scroll_area->setStyleSheet("border: 0px solid black;");
    list_scroll_area->setFixedHeight(700);
    layout->addWidget(list_scroll_area);

    full_list_frame = new QFrame(this);
    full_list_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    full_list_frame->setLayout(full_list_layout);

    search_list_frame = new QFrame(this);
    search_list_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    search_list_frame->setLayout(search_list_layout);
    search_spacer = nullptr;

    stack = new QStackedWidget(this);
    list_scroll_area->setWidget(stack);
    stack->addWidget(full_list_frame);
    stack->addWidget(search_list_frame);
}


void XXX::insertAllPersonItems()
{
    for (auto person : persons) 
        addPerson(person, full_list_layout);
    QSpacerItem* si = new QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    full_list_layout->addItem(si);
}


void XXX::searchForPerson()
{
    list_scroll_area->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(0);

    if (search_edit->text().isEmpty()) {
        stack->setCurrentIndex(0);
        return;
    }

    for (auto w : widgets) {
        delete w;
        widgets.removeOne(w);
    }

    if (search_spacer != nullptr) {
        search_list_layout->removeItem(search_spacer);
        delete search_spacer;
    }   

    search_spacer = new QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);

    stack->setCurrentIndex(1);
    for (auto person : persons) {
        if (person.info.legal_name.contains(search_edit->text()))
            addPerson(person, search_list_layout);
    }

    search_list_layout->addItem(search_spacer);
}
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]